# stopping a setTimeout function

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so i have a very simple image slide show here it is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRn93/)

as you guys can see it works fine when you click start. however when you click stop the function keeps on going here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $('img.hidden').hide();
    $('img.top').show();

    $('input').click(function(){
            var value = $('input').attr("value");

    if(value == "start"){

    $(this).attr("value","stop");
    startShow();

    }else if(value == "stop"){
            $(this).attr("value","start");
            alert('stopped');
            clearTimeout(timer);

        }   
    });

 });

 function startShow(){
   var $top = $('img.top').attr("src");
   var $last = $('img').last().attr("src");

   if($top != $last ){

    var $topImg = $('img.top');
    var $nextImg = $('img.top').next();

    $topImg.hide();
    $nextImg.show();

    $topImg.removeClass("top");
    $nextImg.addClass("top");
   }
   else{

    var $topImg = $('img.top');
    var $nextImg = $('img').first();

    $topImg.hide();
    $nextImg.show();

    $topImg.removeClass("top");
    $nextImg.addClass("top");

   }
   timer = setTimeout(function() { startShow(); }, 2000);
};
```

Comment: Any reason you're calling `setTimeout` repeatedly instead of calling `setInterval` once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your variable's scope.  Move `var timer;` outside your document ready function and it will work.  Of course that makes it a global, which is bad.  So you might want to instead move StartShow into your document ready function.

Answer (score 2):

`timer` is declared as a local variable in the `$(document).ready` function, therefore it is not available in the `startShow` function.

The solution is to make `timer` a global variable, or better yet reorganize your code to use closure.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPWpv/2/)

Let me explain what's going on with an example.

```
function main() {
  var x = 3; // declare a local copy of x, available only in this function
  setValueOfX(); // Try to change the value of x (doesn't work)
  console.log(x); //Prints 3
}

function setValueOfX() {
  x = 12; // You would expect this to change the value of x, but it only changes the value of the global x (window.x), not the local x, so this won't work
}
main();
```

Answer (score 2):

`startShow` is assigning the global variable `timer`, but when you call `clearTimeout` you're inside the `document.ready(function() {...})` where a local variable `timer` was declared. That local variable shadows the global variable.

Either get rid of the `var timer;` declaration, or move `startShow()` inside the ready function.